# Using Lua, how can I run a function whenever the cursor moves?

Tags: vimscript, neovim, lua

I want a function to fire whenever the cursor moves. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run anything automatically in Vim/Neovim after an event such as a file save(`BufWrite`) or your cursor moving(`CursorMoved`) we can use an autocommand.

Here is the Lua implementation for your specific case:

```lua
vim.cmd[[
  augroup cursor_moved
    autocmd!
    autocmd CursorMoved FileName source <afile> | execute 'lua foo(arg1,arg2)'
  augroup end
]]
```

For more information on autocommands read https://neovim.io/doc/user/autocmd.html

Be careful when using autocommands as they are very powerful and can easily break your editor.

Comment: Wrapping with `vim.cmd` is certainly an option, but since OP asked for a lua-based solution, you should use `:h nvim_create_autocmd()`.